# Windows 8.1 override for windows display language registry location

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

I need to programmatically set the windows display language (control panel>language>advanced Settings) so that English (United States) is selected. Is there a registry key that I can set this to? I think it would be located here but not sure what to change :

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\MUI\UILanguages

Does any one know where or how to set this in the registry? Or maybe there is a command I can run? The goal is so that the user does not have to manually do this in the control panel.

TIA

Comment: there's plenty of ways of setting registry keys programmatically, but you haven't mentioned ANYTHING about how/what you're doing. e.g. C? c++? c#? delphi? powershell? cli? telekinesis?

Comment: Oh Sorry, it can be command line (CMD) or even poweshell. It is through SCCM. I am installing the language pack and then would like it to then be selected.